# Upgrading react-scripts to 4.x.x breaks my app

Tags: reactjs, react-scripts

I have been developing a frontend app using React (v16.44.0, cannot upgrade to v17 yet due to a dependency), react-scripts v3.4.4, Typescript (v3.9.9) and React-Bootstrap (v1.5.1) for a few months and all is going well.

However, `react-scripts` have been updated recently to a v4, and upgrading breaks the whole app. I am concerned with securities issues with react-scripts v3. I also would like to upgrade Typescript to v4+, there seem to be an incompatibility btw Typescript 4 and react-scripts 3 related to eslint. Various deprecation warnings are also stacking up.

When I enable react-scripts v4.0.3, run `npm start` to launch the development server, Firefox (v78.8) throws:

> "ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined" in "node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:347".

Apparently `webidl-conversions` is required by bootstrap. I have searched about the `SharedArrayBuffer` issue, apparently it requires enabling additional headers, but I could not find how to add them using the `npm start` webserver.

[Edit: upgraded Firefox to v86, still have the issue but I have not tried to configure it yet.]

If I try with Chrome (v89), I have:

> "TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object" on "node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/utils.js:48"

which also seem to be required by Bootstrap.

I do not have a dependency on Bootstrap per se, I use the `react-bootstrap` implementation. However, I use `bootstrap-scss` for the (S)CSS part.

I can upload full stack traces if needed. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "ab-concept-backoffice",
  "version": "42.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^1.2.34",
    "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^5.15.2",
    "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.14",
    "bootstrap-scss": "^4.6.0",
    "classnames": "^2.2.6",
    "date-fns": "^2.17.0",
    "filesize": "^6.1.0",
    "flux": "^4.0.1",
    "immutable": "^4.0.0-rc.12",
    "jsdom": "^16.5.1",
    "lz-string": "^1.4.4",
    "monet": "^0.9.1",
    "query-string": "^6.14.0",
    "react": "^16.14.0",
    "react-autosuggest": "^10.1.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^1.5.1",
    "react-color": "^2.19.3",
    "react-cookie": "^4.0.3",
    "react-day-picker": "^7.4.8",
    "react-dom": "^16.14.0",
    "react-gravatar": "^2.6.3",
    "react-html5-camera-photo": "^1.5.4",
    "react-number-format": "^4.4.4",
    "react-phone-number-input": "^3.1.16",
    "react-process-string": "^1.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^4.1.0",
    "react-sketch": "^0.5.1",
    "react-three-state-checkbox": "^1.3.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "analyze": "source-map-explorer 'build/static/js/*.js'",
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "npm version patch && react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not ie <= 11",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/classnames": "^2.2.11",
    "@types/humanize-duration": "^3.18.0",
    "@types/lz-string": "^1.3.34",
    "@types/md5": "^2.3.0",
    "@types/node": "^14.14.31",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.2",
    "@types/react-autosuggest": "^10.1.2",
    "@types/react-color": "^3.0.4",
    "@types/react-gravatar": "^2.6.8",
    "@types/react-phone-number-input": "^3.0.6",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.1.7",
    "@types/react-select": "^4.0.13",
    "sass": "^1.32.8",
    "typescript": "^4.2.3"
  }
}
```

Firefox stack trace:

```
ReferenceError: SharedArrayBuffer is not defined
./node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js
node_modules/webidl-conversions/lib/index.js:347

  344 | 
  345 | const abByteLengthGetter =
  346 |     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(ArrayBuffer.prototype, "byteLength").get;
> 347 | const sabByteLengthGetter =
  348 |     Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(SharedArrayBuffer.prototype, "byteLength").get;
  349 | 
  350 | function isNonSharedArrayBuffer(V) {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

./node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:3
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

./node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js:3
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

./node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js:3
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150

  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {

1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:39420:18
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856

  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }

checkDeferredModules
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:45

  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 

webpackJsonpCallback
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:32

  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;

(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:95
```

Chrome stack trace:

```
TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object
./node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/utils.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/utils.js:48
  45 | 
  46 | const iterInternalSymbol = Symbol("internal");
  47 | const IteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf([][Symbol.iterator]()));
> 48 | const AsyncIteratorPrototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(Object.getPrototypeOf(async function* () {}).prototype);
  49 | 
  50 | function isArrayIndexPropName(P) {
  51 |   if (typeof P !== "string") {
View compiled
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/dist/URL.js:4
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/webidl2js-wrapper.js:3
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
./node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js
node_modules/whatwg-url/index.js:3
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
▶ 2 stack frames were collapsed.
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
fn
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:150
  147 |         );
  148 |         hotCurrentParents = [];
  149 |     }
> 150 |     return __webpack_require__(request);
      | ^  151 | };
  152 | var ObjectFactory = function ObjectFactory(name) {
  153 |     return {
View compiled
1
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:39420:18
__webpack_require__
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:856
  853 | 
  854 | __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.init();
  855 | try {
> 856 |     modules[moduleId].call(module.exports, module, module.exports, hotCreateRequire(moduleId));
      | ^  857 | } finally {
  858 |     __webpack_require__.$Refresh$.cleanup(moduleId);
  859 | }
View compiled
checkDeferredModules
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:45
  42 |  }
  43 |  if(fulfilled) {
  44 |      deferredModules.splice(i--, 1);
> 45 |      result = __webpack_require__(__webpack_require__.s = deferredModule[0]);
     | ^  46 |  }
  47 | }
  48 | 
View compiled
Array.webpackJsonpCallback [as push]
/home/vion/workspace/ab-concept-frontend/webpack/bootstrap:32
  29 |  deferredModules.push.apply(deferredModules, executeModules || []);
  30 | 
  31 |  // run deferred modules when all chunks ready
> 32 |  return checkDeferredModules();
     | ^  33 | };
  34 | function checkDeferredModules() {
  35 |  var result;
View compiled
(anonymous function)
http://localhost:3000/static/js/main.chunk.js:1:95
```

Comment: please add the dependencies you have in your package.json to the question so we can replicate the issue

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's hard to tell exactly without your full `package.json`, but it seems that it's not related to the update of `react-scripts` itself, but instead probably an updgrade on another library that you are depending on that uses `SharedArrayBuffer` which [is not supported in Firefox v78](https://caniuse.com/?search=SharedArrayBuffer)

**Edit**: OP found out that the [problematic package was `react-sketch`](https://github.com/tbolis/react-sketch/issues/126)

As per the other error, it seems to be related, but don't know exactly why it happens. Anyhow, found [this issue](https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url/issues/166) in their Github page and one suggestion is to [upgrade `jsdom` to version `>=16.3`](https://github.com/jsdom/whatwg-url/issues/166#issuecomment-685678185) (if you are using it)

Comment: Jsdom is a dependency of react-scripts, so yes it is probably related due to some dependency somewhere. I do not known if I can upgrade jsdom separately, I will try that. Upgrading Firefox may be an option too (I am using Debian Sid so that will not be that easy, but doable), but I am worried end users might not have the freedom to upgrade.

Comment: @scand1sk could you provide your `package.json` so that's easier to help you :) ?

Comment: Done. I also upgraded Firefox to v86 and jsdom to 16.5.1, still have issues. I will post stack traces. Actually stack trace shows errors in webpack/bootstrap, but I am not sure it really is the "Bootstrap" library.

Comment: @scand1sk I have tried to reproduce locally and I don't come across any error. I know you have already answered this, but double chekcing, have you `rm -rf node_modules` and tried again? secondly, have you previously ejected your project?

Comment: Yes, I did clean package-lock and node_modules (and did it again just now for sure). I did not eject the project. Should I? Will I still be able to perform npm start and npm build if I eject the project?

Comment: @scand1sk no no you shouldn't, just wondering. What's your nodejs version installed?

Comment: npm --version
7.6.2. I also have nodejs v12.21.0 installed.

Comment: I know that npm uses nodejs in the background but I do not actually interact with it. I cannot rember how nodejs was installed on my development environment (Debian Sid). I use plain Apache in production.

Comment: If my issue is not reproducible on an empty project I guess I am doomed to recreate my project bit by bit until the error is triggered again :/

Comment: @scand1sk I don't know what else could be. It works in my computer with your exact same versions and package.json. If npm cache clean --force + deleting node modules and lock + and reinstalling doesnt' work, you could clone your repo on a different direcotry and try again. don't know what else could be tried if not, sorry.

Comment: @scand1sk have you tried to clone and install again?

Comment: OK. I have spend a whole day reconstructing the application module by module to see what triggered the error. And it was… drum rolls… the react-sketch dependency that caused the error (as soon as it is imported). Bug is filled here https://github.com/tbolis/react-sketch/issues/126. React-sketch has no much activity, I will have to search for an alternative (sigh).

Comment: @scand1sk Glad that you managed to find it. I was checking at the versions of that library, and it seems that in version <=0.4.4 didn't use jsdom, but it does in >=0.5.0. Probably when you updated react-scripts, it installed the new version of that library due to not being in versioned as a breaking change. In the long term I would try to remove that dependency since it doesn't seem to be manitained, but in the meantime you could try downgrading it to v4.4.0, then it might work

Comment: @scand1sk     `"react-sketch": "0.4.4"` (without `^`) in your package.json might do the trick

Comment: I found out that "react-sketch2" is a thing, which is a npm publication of react-sketch 0.5.7. Now there was also a Typescript issue: I had a file that had "declare module "react-sketch" which was also part of the issue. It is no longer required with the latest version of react-sketch.

Comment: Still need some help : types/index.d.ts declares module "react-sketch" although the new version is called "react-sketch2". As a result I get the error "File xxx/node_modules/react-sketch2/types/index.d.ts is not a module". How to solve this discrepancy?

Comment: Well, I copied the index.d.ts to my src and changed the declaration to "react-sketch2". Hacky, but it works.

Comment: @scand1sk yes don't think you have another option, either that or forking yourself the repo. I would try to move away from that library tho sooner or later though.

Comment: I had the same problem and fixed it by replace react-sketch with react-sketch2

Answer (score 1):

Did you apply each migration described in the [changelog](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)?

They also suggest you delete node_modules if you break your app when updating from 3.4 to 4.

```
NOTE: You may need to delete your node_modules folder and reinstall your dependencies by running yarn (or npm install) if you encounter errors after upgrading.
```

Try deleting it and running `npm install`

Comment: Yes I did delete package-lock.json and node_modules. Did not help.
Changelog does not give much migration tricks.
What hits me is that the bugs I encounter do not seem to be actually related to react-scripts…

Answer (score 0):

You can download Bootstrap CSS files manually and save them in project files.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I used react-bootstrap the resulting code it very tightly coupled with Bootstrap (which was probably not good, but hard to undo).

Comment: You don’t have to remove react-bootstrap, just bootstrap itself. First doesn’t depend on second afaik. Just require using styles from bootstrap which you can add manually

Answer (score 0):

Try:

Deleting your node_modules and package-lock.json

```
// This normally fixes my issue when going back to old react projects
npm cache clean --force 

run npm install

run npm run start
```

Comment: Already suggested by another answer. Did not work.